# How to call method stopAnimator() from onCreate() in activity?The stopAnimator() is present in the recyclerViewHolder class

Tags: android, oop, android-5.0-lollipop, android-recyclerview

In Acivity in onCreate() method the code is as shown in below.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_recording_list);
  tplay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"play",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                if(mp.isPlaying()){
                    tplay.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.ic_media_play);
                    mp.pause();

                }else {
                    mp.start();
                            //Here i want to call method which is present in recycler view holder.The Method is stopAnimator() from my viewholder class
                }



            }
        });
```

The MyViewHolder class is in MyAdapter class(MyViewHolder is inner class of MyAdapter and MyAdapter is inner class of activity).the adapter class code is below:

```
private class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
    private final List<String> recordList;

    public MyAdapter(List<String> recordList) {
        this.recordList=recordList;


    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View itemLayoutView = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.song_item, null);
        MyViewHolder myViewHolder= new MyViewHolder(itemLayoutView);
        return myViewHolder;

    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder viewHolder,int i) {
        viewHolder.txtViewTitle.setText(recordList.get(i));

        /***
         * 2nd method to use the onclick listener on Recycler view
         */
        /*viewHolder.txtViewTitle.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),""+recordList.get(i),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                try {
                    mp.reset();
                    mp.setDataSource(SD_PATH + Recording.get(i));
                    mp.prepare();
                    mp.start();
                } catch (Exception e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });*/
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return recordList.size();
    }


    class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{

        //If u have any other view like layout or button get refrence of that and implement the on click listener on that
        public TextView txtViewTitle;
        public EqualizerView equalizer;

        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            txtViewTitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.text1);
            equalizer = (EqualizerView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.equalizer_view);
            txtViewTitle.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),""+recordList.get(getPosition()),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            try {
                mp.reset();
                mp.setDataSource(SD_PATH + Recording.get(getPosition()));
                mp.prepare();
                mp.start();
                if(mp.isPlaying()){
                    tplay.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.ic_media_pause);
                    equalizer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    equalizer.animateBars(); // Whenever you want to tart the animation

                }
            } catch (Exception e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }



        }



        public void stopAnimator() {
            if (equalizer.isAnimating()){
                equalizer.stopBars();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Can anybody help me please..!!!!!.
      The method which i wrote in MyViewHolder class is stopAnimator() as shown in above code.The method is used to stop the equalizer. This method i want to call from the activity from the tplay onclickListener.How can i achieve this?.The equilizer is custom view which i used from the library  [Mini Equalizer Library](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/1558)  .

Comment: Probably creating Object of `MyViewHolder` class in onCreate method? then use object to call `stopAnimator` method

Comment: Its not working.My mistake i forget to mention the ViewHolder class is inner class of MyAdapter. Edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

you could create object from the class then you could call any method in the class

```
MyViewHolder  objView=new MyViewHolder (Your_View);
    objView.stopAnimator() ;
```

Comment: Its giving me error "com.playAndRecord.eletanpuratabla.RecordingListActivity.MyAdapter is not an enclosing class". Actually the MyViewHolder inner class of MyAdapter.